# OpenVPN client config no connect

Tags: openvpn

I Tried in my OpenVPN Server with SoftEther VPN Server and download OpenVpn Config file with Different port and disable firewall also add openvpn port

when tried wih openvpn client i get error:

```
Wed Nov 20 13:03:28 2019 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
Wed Nov 20 13:03:28 2019 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25343
Wed Nov 20 13:03:28 2019 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
Wed Nov 20 13:03:28 2019 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'
Wed Nov 20 13:03:28 2019 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'echo all on'
Wed Nov 20 13:03:28 2019 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'bytecount 5'
Wed Nov 20 13:03:28 2019 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'
Wed Nov 20 13:03:28 2019 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
Wed Nov 20 13:03:30 2019 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'username "Auth" "mohsen"'
Wed Nov 20 13:03:30 2019 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'password [...]'
Wed Nov 20 13:03:30 2019 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1574242410,RESOLVE,,,,,,
Wed Nov 20 13:03:30 2019 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]85.18.xxx.xxx:50179
Wed Nov 20 13:03:30 2019 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
Wed Nov 20 13:03:30 2019 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]85.18.xxx.xxx:50179 [nonblock]
Wed Nov 20 13:03:30 2019 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1574242410,TCP_CONNECT,,,,,,
```

Also Openvpn config file is like:

```
dev tap
proto udp
remote 85.18.xxx.xxx 50179
cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA1
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
client
verb 3
auth-user-pass

<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
key... for security hidden key
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>

<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
key... for security hidden key
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

</cert>

<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
key... for security hidden key
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

</key>
```

error is

Wed Nov 20 13:05:30 2019 TCP: connect to [AF_INET]85.18.xxx.xxx:50179 failed: Unknown error

Answer (score 0):

`Unknown error` usually indicates that the OpenVPN client has failed to connect to the server. Is the port running on the server, can the client reach the server? Are there any firewall rules that might prevent connectivity?

Comment: no firewall enabled in server also add port 50179 tcp/udp to in server firewall